# PL/SQL Condition statement inside a WHERE statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

What am I doing wrong here I cant for the life of me figure this out I know it cant be this hard right?

```
SELECT SCALED_SCORE 
FROM NEUROCOG.SCALED_SCORE_RAW 
WHERE DDID = 2737

AND (CASE 

  WHEN SYNTAX = '>=' THEN AND 6 BETWEEN RAW_SCORE_START AND RAW_SCORE_END;
  WHEN SYNTAX = '<=' THEN AND 6 BETWEEN RAW_SCORE_END AND RAW_SCORE_START;
  WHEN SYNTAX IS NULL THEN AND 6 BETWEEN RAW_SCORE_START AND RAW_SCORE_END;

END CASE);
```

please help

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question

Comment: Explain some more of what are you trying to do, just with the code  I don't know how to help you. And if this help, please take a look at the CASE statement in PL-SQL: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What should this query do?

Comment: @deharodk: the question is **not** showing any PL/SQL so your link doesn't apply here. There is a big difference between the PL/SQL CASE statement and the (plain) SQL CASE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny. A collegue had exactly the same issue today. Are you him? :)

You cannot have a condition like that in a where clause. A `case` can only return a value (and not even a boolean value/comparison result).

But you can just use `AND` to combine the condition you want with the 'precondition' of having a certain 'syntax'. Hard to put down in words, but the query should look just like this:

```
SELECT SCALED_SCORE 
FROM NEUROCOG.SCALED_SCORE_RAW 
WHERE DDID = 2737
AND (
  (SYNTAX = '>=' AND 6 BETWEEN RAW_SCORE_START AND RAW_SCORE_END) OR
  (SYNTAX = '<=' AND 6 BETWEEN RAW_SCORE_END AND RAW_SCORE_START) OR
  (SYNTAX IS NULL AND 6 BETWEEN RAW_SCORE_START AND RAW_SCORE_END)
)
```

That query is a literal translation of what you seemed to try.

A slightly different approach could work as well. `BETWEEN .. AND ..` expects two numeric expressions, each of which can be a case statement, so you could write something like this:

```
SELECT SCALED_SCORE 
FROM NEUROCOG.SCALED_SCORE_RAW 
WHERE DDID = 2737
AND (
  6 BETWEEN 
      CASE WHEN SYNTAX = '<=' THEN RAW_SCORE_END ELSE RAW_SCORE_START END 
    AND 
      CASE WHEN SYNTAX = '<=' THEN RAW_SCORE_START ELSE RAW_SCORE_END END 
)
```

Is it better, faster? I don't know. More readable? In this case maybe not, but I can't hurt to have a trick like this up your sleeve. Note that this query is slightly different than the previous one. The other one has no catch for syntaxes other than >=, <= and NULL, while this one falls back every SYNTAX that is not '<=' to a forward range.

Comment: LOL I wished I asked / bugged my co-worker about this and he only helped me part way; but your examples works like a champ!! thanks a ton!!!